# Compact way to write a list of lists

Tags: list, nested-lists

I am writing a program that outputs a list of ordered lists of numbers. Say the output is as follows:

`[1,1,1]; 
[1,1,2]`

I would like to look at the output by eye and make some sense of it, but my output is hundreds to thousands of lines long. I would like to write the output in the following more compact format: `[1,1,1/2]`, where the slash indicates that in the third slot I can have a 1 or a 2. So, for a longer example, `[1/2, 1/3, 5, 8/9]` would be the compact way of writing `[1,1,5,8];[1,1,5,9];[1,3,5,8];` etc. Can anyone suggest a pseudocode algorithm for accomplishing this?

Edit: All of the lists are the same length. Also, I expect in general to have multiple lists at the end. For example {[1,1,2], [1,1,3], [1,2,4]} should become {[1,1,2/3], [1,2,4]}.

Comment: My list of lists is in order ([1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,1,4], etc.) so right now I check if two consecutive lists have the same entry in every column but the last. If so, I'll output "1,1,1/2" and then check if the next list also matches in every column but the last; if it does, as in my example, I'll append "/4", if not I start over with the new sequence in the first N-1 columns. It accomplishes what I want, but only for the very last column.

Answer (score 0):

What'd I do is use a hash at each element in the first list. You'd then iterate through the remaining lists, and for each position in the other lists, you'd check against the hash in the first / original list for that index to see if you'd seen it before. So you'd end up with something like:

```
[1 : {1}, 1: {1, 3}, 5: {5}, 8: {8, 9}]
```

And then when printing / formatting the list, you'd just print each key in the hash, except you'd use slashes or whatever.

EDIT: Bad Psuedocode (python)(untested):

```
def shorten_list(list_of_lists):
primary_list = list_of_lists[0]
hash_values = [{} * len(primary_list)]

for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    current_list = list_of_lists[i]
    for j in range(current_list):
        num = current_list[j]
        if num not in hash_values[j]:
            hash_values[j] = j

for i in range(len(hash_values)):
    current_dict = hash_values[i]
    print primary_list[i]
    for key in current_dict:
        if key != primary_list[i]:
            print '/', key
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's actual code to sort the lists the way you wanted. But maybe the most useful visualization would be a scatter plot. Import the data into your favorite spreadsheet, and plot away.

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
  var numbers = [
    [1, 1, 5, 8],
    [1, 1, 5, 9],
    [1, 3, 5],
    [1, 1, 5, 10, 15]];

  $('#output').text(JSON.stringify(compactNumbers(numbers)));
});

function compactNumbers(numberlists){
  var output = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < numberlists.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < numberlists[i].length; j++) {
      if(!output[j]) output[j] = [];
      if($.inArray(numberlists[i][j], output[j]) == -1){
        output[j].push(numberlists[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return(output);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```